# Create date and hour columns from date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I want to create a temp table where I give it a starting and ending date (pricedate). Then the results are those dates in one column and the hour of each day in the other column.

It would look like this:

```
date       hour
------------------
1/17/19     1
1/17/19     2
1/17/19     3
   .        .
   .        .
1/17/19    24
1/18/19     1
1/18/19     2
1/18/19     3
   .        .
   .        .
   .        .
```

So it seems like I want to use generate_series for the hour. But not sure how to match that up with dates.

This is not getting it done for me:

```
WITH hrs AS (SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,24)),
pricedate AS (SELECT * FROM generate_series('2018-01-24', '2018-01-26', interval '1 day'))


SELECT pricedate, hrs
WHERE pricedate BETWEEN '2018-01-24' AND '2018-01-26'
ORDER BY pricedate, hour
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross join`:

```
WITH hrs AS (
       SELECT gs.hr
       FROM generate_series(1,24) gs(hr)
      ),
      pricedate AS (
       SELECT gs.priceate
       FROM generate_series('2018-01-24', '2018-01-26', interval '1 day') gs(pricedate)
      )
SELECT pricedate.pricedate, hrs.hr
FROM hrs CROSS JOIN pricedate
WHERE pricedate.pricedate BETWEEN '2018-01-24' AND '2018-01-26'
ORDER BY pricedate.pricedate, hrs.hour
```

Comment: nice. I don't think you even need the where clause. I forgot about the cross join feature! That's the key to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
select d::date as date, extract(hour from d)::int+ 1 as hour
from generate_series('2018-01-24', '2018-01-26 23:00', interval '1 hour') s(d)

    date    | hour 
------------+------
 2018-01-24 |    1
 2018-01-24 |    2
 2018-01-24 |    3
 2018-01-24 |    4
...
```

Comment: What is the "s(d)" part? I am unfamiliar with that kind of syntax. What is that doing? Defining it as a series named "d"?

Comment: It's an alias with a column name. Yes, it defines generated timestamps as `d`.

Comment: Why the s(d), and not just "AS d"? That's just your style?

Comment: `s(d)` is more formal. `s` is like a table name, `d` is a column. Hence you can use `select s.d ...` But in general it's a matter of style.

Comment: This only give hour 1 on the last day.

Comment: @otterdog2000- you can easily control the range by the input timestamps. The answer updated.